# How to connect Contact form 7 and Cloudpayments?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I tied the Cloudpayments payment system to the Contact form 7 plugin form on the Wordpress site. How can I make the Contact form 7 form be sent only after successful payment? Now, when filling out the form fields and clicking the submit button, the form is sent, after that Cloudpayments opens. And you need to make sure that when you click on the submit form button, the form is not sent, but the payment system window opens, and only then, the form is sent, that is, after payment.

Here is the script that processes the payment

```
const payPopup = () => {
  var widget = new cp.CloudPayments();
  widget.pay('auth', // или 'charge'
      { //options
          publicId: publicId, //id из личного кабинета
          description: globalText, //назначение
          amount: globalAmount, //сумма
          currency: 'RUB', //валюта
          accountId: nameUser.value, //идентификатор плательщика (необязательно)
          //invoiceId: '1234567', //номер заказа  (необязательно)
          //email: 'user@example.com', //email плательщика (необязательно)
          skin: "mini", //дизайн виджета (необязательно)
          autoClose: 3, //время в секундах до авто-закрытия виджета (необязательный)
          data: {
              myProp: 'myProp value'
          },
          configuration: {
              common: {
                  successRedirectUrl: "/success-pay", // адреса для перенаправления
                  failRedirectUrl: "/fail-pay"        // при оплате по Tinkoff Pay
              }
          },
      },
      {
          onSuccess: function () { // success
              //action success pay
          },
          onFail: function (reason, options) { // fail
              //action fail pay
          },
          onComplete: function () { //Вызывается как только виджет получает от api.cloudpayments ответ с результатом транзакции.
              //например вызов вашей аналитики
          }
      }
  )
};
```

That's how I call the payment widget. When submitting a form, it is called

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
  if ( '946' == event.detail.contactFormId) {
    payPopup(); // - call to payment system popup
  }
}, false );
```

What can I do to make everything work as I need it?